# cannot install my hp printer with hp-setup

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, hplip

I used to install my HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP running sudo hp-setup without a problem. The program would just download the appropriate driver from the web and everything was good to go.

Now I tried to do the same but it seems like hp-setup won't even try to download it, and I coudln't find where to get it.

I get the following message:

```
Using queue name: HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP
Locating PPD file... Please wait.
error: No PPD found for model laserjet_professional_m1132_mfp using old algorithm.
error: Unable to find an appropriate PPD file.

Would you like to specify the path to the correct PPD file to use (y=yes, n=no*, q=quit) ? 
error: PPD file required. Setup cannot continue. Exiting.
```

Anybody had a similar trouble? I'm running ubuntu 14.10 64 bit, with hplip 3.14.16-1ubuntu1

```
$ uname -a
Linux touch 3.16.0-34-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 18:02:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

Test this:

Connect printer with the computer and turn it on.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall hplip printer-driver-hpijs printer-driver-hpcups openprinting-ppds printer-driver-postscript-hp cups cups-filter printer-driver-gutenprint
hp-setup -i
```

Once you press enter, the automatic installation will download the needed packages for the hardware. Let the installation finished. Make sure that the printer is connected along installation process.

Once you finished the installation, you can try to print and scan using the device. The installation will download the proprietary package from HP repository. You can try to check the printer configuration once after installation finished. Using HP LIP, you can also try to run the basic HP printer and scanner utilities to make sure that all devices are running correctly.

Source: http://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP

Answer (score 2):

The cups service must be running. Run as root

```
service cups start
```